# The session factory has not been initialized

Tags: java, hibernate

```
public Session openTxCoreSession()
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("openTxCoreSession() start...");

            TxCoreSessionFactory sessionFactory =
                TxCoreSessionFactory.getInstance("conf/txcore.cfg.xml");
            System.out.println("Session factory created....");

            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

            coreTransaction = session.beginTransaction();
            coreConnection = session.connection();
            System.out.println("session created");
            return session;
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here are Exceptions-

```
The session factory has not been initialized.
java.lang.RuntimeException: The session factory has not been initialized.
at com.uniteller.txcore.base._BaseRootDAO.getSessionFactory(_BaseRootDAO.java:86)
at com.uniteller.txcore.base._BaseRootDAO.createSession(_BaseRootDAO.java:116)
at com.uniteller.txcore.TxCoreSessionFactory.openSession(TxCoreSessionFactory.java:77)
at com.uniteller.tools.databroker.DataBroker.openTxCoreSession(DataBroker.java:674)
at com.uniteller.tools.databroker.DataBroker.run(DataBroker.java:90)
at com.uniteller.tools.databroker.DataBrokerImplementer.main(DataBrokerImplementer.java:27)
```

Comment: No root cause is showing, I have posted exception.

Comment: am not seeing buildSessionFactory() in your code can u check?

Comment: I have no idea what is `TxCoreSessionFactory` as it is not the class provided by Hibernate. So please provide the code of  `TxCoreSessionFactory.getInstance()`

Comment: public static TxCoreSessionFactory getInstance(String _configFile)
  throws Exception
 {
  if (instance_U == null)
  {
   instance_U = new TxCoreSessionFactory();
   instance_U.init(_configFile);
  }

  return instance_U;
 }

Comment: Here is init()----- private void init(String _configFile) throws Exception
 {
  File _file= new File(_configFile);

  Configuration _hibConfig = new Configuration();
  SessionFactory _hibSessionFactory =
   _hibConfig.configure(_file).buildSessionFactory();
  //configFileName_s = _configFile;
  //_RootDAO.setSessionFactory(configFileName_s, _hibSessionFactory);
 }

Answer (score 0):

This Code May Help You.

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration().Configure("conf/txcore.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction=session.beginTransaction();
```